# Going back to FOR loop from IF in VBA

Tags: vba

I want to initiate a FOR loop, within which I will check a condition with IF, and if the IF condition is satisfied - I have to do something (within the IF) and then GO back to the FOR loop without executing the command below:

For (condition 1)

If (condition 2) Then
          commands
        Go back to the FOR loop and increment it by 1
   End if

Other commands within FOR ( these need not be executed if the above IF loop is satisfied)

Next i  ( increments the FOR loop)

Comment: There's no such thing as an IF loop. Just use `else` for the rest... or use a label at the end of the block and a `goto` to skip to it

Comment: NOTE: `Next i` does not always mean `increment i by one`

Comment: indent the pseudo-code that you posted by 4 spaces, so that it shows up as code

Answer (score 2):

Use Else to do when it is not true. Like this:

```
For i = 1 to 100
    If i mod 2 = 0 then
        'do some code when true
    Else
        'do some code when false
    End if
Next i
```

Or if you only care when the condition is not true then do it this way using `Not`:

```
For i = 1 to 100
    If  Not i mod 2 = 0 then
       'do some code
    End if
Next i
```